# Cuál sería la traducción de Nice, Great y Good Question?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos

Esto se refiere a las [Medallas](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) de StackOverflow.

Tengo:

Nice Question => **?????????????** | Question score of 10 or more

Good Question =>  Buena pregunta | Question score of 25 or more

Great Question => Gran pregunta | Question score of 100 or more

Question score of **X** or more => Pregunta con puntaje de **X** o más

Pero `Nice Question` cómo la traduciría y todavía pueda diferenciarla de las otras.

Tengo todas estas opciones de google translator pero no me convence ninguna:

```
agradable | amable | bonito | precioso | bien | bueno | lindo | muy |  Simpático | majo | bastante | guapo
```

Comment: Por qué el voto negativo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es una pregunta difícil. Como ya se ha dicho, generalmente tanto "nice" como "good" se suelen traducir como "buena". No todos los idiomas tienen los mismos matices para las calificaciones y no todos los niveles tienen un equivalente exacto.

Creo que "aceptable" se queda bastante por debajo de "nice", e incluso descalificaría a las respuestas que no llegaran al "nice", que quedarían como "inaceptables".

Yo propongo romper los esquemas y construir desde cero una escala propia en español. Por ejemplo:

- Nice Question => Buena pregunta
- Good Question => Muy buena pregunta
- Great Question => Gran pregunta

Si se quiere evitar el uso del superlativo (muy buena), se puede usar otra escala:

- Nice Question => Buena pregunta
- Good Question => Gran pregunta
- Great Question => Excelente pregunta

Comment: gracias...muy buena idea, me gusta más la segunda opción

Comment: @Flamma Es una buena respuesta, y por tanto no escribo la mía, pero me gustaría sugerir: Gran -> Estupenda -> Excelente. De esta forma me reservaría el término "buena", que debería ser aplicable a todas las que no sean "malas".

Answer (score 2):

`Nice` has in spanish the same translation as `Good`, while the connotation is really different.

In `Buena pregunta`, the adjective `Buena` relies on the context to have one meaning or another.

**Buena as Nice**

- **Robert**: El otro día me encontré un cocodrilo en el baño
- **Maria**: Qué hacía un cocodrilo en tu baño?
- **Robert**: Buena pregunta. <*meaning Nice Question*>

---

**Buena as Good**

- **Robert**: He implementado las comunicaciones usando ActiveMQ
- **Maria**: Por qué ActiveMQ y no RabbitMQ o Fuse?
- **Robert**: Buena pregunta. <*meaning Good Question*>

Comment: Si ese es el problema que como tienen la misma traduccion me haria falta una alternativa para diferenciarla de good question

Answer (score 1):

I would read it as follows:

- Nice Question: Pregunta aceptable (or something like that)
- Good Question: Buena preguna
- Great Question: Excelente pregunta

This translation is not exact, but in this case I think it would help.

Comment: Gracias...quiero ver si aparece otra mejor que aceptable..no se si es mi por mi ideosincracia pero acpetable me suena a algo que cumple con el minimo de requisitos...no se no me gusta como equivalente para nice en este caso

Comment: La verdad a mí tampoco me convence mucho, pero no se me ocurre otra palabra por ahora.

Comment: la idea seria buscar una traduccion `aceptable` para `Nice Question` y diferenciarla de `Good Question` :)

Comment: Tal vez pensando la diferencia en inglés pueda ayudar... ¿Cuál sería la diferencia de "good question" and "nice question" en inglés?

Comment: Para mi nice seria más parecido a agradable y good como bueno/a

Comment: Puede ser una posibilidad, dado que "agradable" sería la traducción literal de "nice". Pero, personalmente, me sucede lo mismo que a tí con "aceptable". No sé, habrá que ver si alguien llega con una mejor traducción.